# Swift Json decoding with unsure incoming data

Tags: arrays, json, swift, object, decoding

I'm struggeling to decode some Json data in swift.

My back-end api will return me either an array of X or an object with (at least) one property named "items" of type array of X.

I've searched but found no solutions. Do you have any ?

```
struct A: Decodable {
   var items: [X]
   // some other optional properties

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       // Sometimes I receive the correct A object
       // Sometimes I only receive the array of X without the surrounding object of type A.
   }
}
```

And to make things worst, I'm bound to decode like I was always receiving an object of typa A... :

```
myObjectOfTypeA = try decoder.decode(A.self, from: data)
```

Most of the time, I'll receive a proper A object like this :

```
{
    "items": 
    [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "startsOn": "2021-03-01",
            "endsOn": "2021-12-31"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "startsOn": "2021-04-19",
            "endsOn": "2022-04-04"
        }
    ],
    "next": null,
    "prev": null,
    "count": 2
}
```

But sometimes, I'll receive only the items array like this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "startsOn": "2021-03-01",
        "endsOn": "2021-12-31"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "startsOn": "2021-04-19",
        "endsOn": "2022-04-04"
    }
]
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated because I'm clearly out of ideas myself...

Comment: Use https://quicktype.io/. Path there both cases and it will generate parsing code

Comment: Could you add a json sample that matches what you are describing?

Comment: Is that the top level of your JSON? Do you need the next/previous/count values?

Comment: Yes, the json I've posted are the two possible top level json I can receive. The next/previous/count properties are provided by the back end even if they're not mandatory for me.

Comment: But those json are for different endpoints, right? I mean, you know when one returns first and another one returns the second

Comment: Yes. From two end different points. but some end points returns the old version which provides only the array and other end points returns the new version which provides the object. I have to manage the two smoothly if possible without knowing which kind I'll receive.

Comment: If you get two different JSON strings for different endpoints then the *incoming data* is pretty ***sure*** and you could use a generic type.

Comment: Is it possible that one code handles the two cases without knowing which return I'll get before making the network call ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but a much better choice is to use a generic decoder and decode different types depending on the endpoint.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been very clear. I'm being asked to prepare my app for being ready for a breaking change in the api that will occure in a near future. Right now I get the array but soon in the future, I'll get the object. I have to deliver a version of my app that handles the two cases because we want our user's fleet to be ready before the breaking change occurs... That's why I'm trying to handle the two cases. (Not sure I'm being more clear, sorry again)

Comment: `items = try decoder.decode(A.self, from: data).items` and inside the catch `items = try decoder.decode([X].self, from: data)`. No need to create a custom decoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to try to decode your enclosing type items and catch the error. If it is a type mismatch error try to decode it again. No need to create a custom decoder:

---

```
struct A: Decodable {
   let items: [X]
}
```

---

```
struct X: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let startsOn: Date
    let endsOn: Date
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let json = """
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "startsOn": "2021-03-01",
            "endsOn": "2021-12-31"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "startsOn": "2021-04-19",
            "endsOn": "2022-04-04"
        }
    ],
    "next": null,
    "prev": null,
    "count": 2
}
"""
```

---

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
let items: [X]
do {
    items = try jsonDecoder.decode(A.self, from: Data(json.utf8)).items
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
    items = try jsonDecoder.decode([X].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
} catch {
    items = []
    print(error)
}
print(items)
```

---

It will print the following for both json inputs:

> [X(id: 7, startsOn: 2021-03-01 03:00:00 +0000, endsOn: 2021-12-31 03:00:00 +0000), X(id: 6, startsOn: 2021-04-19 03:00:00 +0000, endsOn: 2022-04-04 03:00:00 +0000)]

Comment: Thank you very much guys. The latest solution worked for me. I was trying to avoid the try-catch because it may be time consuming but until I'm being told the opposite, I'll consider it's fine for me. Thank you all for your help 

Comment: @jbat You are welcome. Do you know how to mark an answer as correct?

Comment: Well, I’ve searched a bit but without success. Maybe it’s so obvious and just in front of my eyes that I don’t see it . Any hint  ?